# Why do using reducerManager gives me incorrect state

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-reducers, ngrx-selectors

I'm using `reducerManager` to add my reducers inside of a global object.

if for example I write

`const reducer = createReducer( initialState, on( doSomething, state => state ) );`

then:

`reducerManager.addReducer( 'reducer', reducer );`

and in my component use select I need to write:

`val:Observable<any> = this.store.select( state => state.reducer.val );`

My question is why can't I just write:

`val:Observable<any> = this.store.select( state => state.val );`

is this the meaning of using a reducer manager or am I getting something wrong?

I've added many reducers to my manager and after writing the name as state property to get my final value, I always get the same store state ( btw do these states are shared, what's the purpose of it ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is a global object.
By using `reducerManager.addReducer( 'reducer', reducer );` you're adding the reducer to the global object, with `reducer` as key.

So your state becomes

```
{
  reducer: reducer()
}
```

To read from the store you always select from the root object, and thus you need to select the state from the `reducer` property.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer, btw do you kow if it's a good practice to use multiple reducers for the same state? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, one reducer can only manage its own state.